Windows Server Failover Cluster - Roles vs Client Access Points
I'm currently working on setting up a prototype failover cluster to replace our singular file server VMs with two clustered nodes.
I was wondering and can't find a good resource on the topic, what would be considered better practice? Creating a new clustered role for each file server or use a single role with multiple client access points named after the old file servers and publishing shares under the respective access points?
For context, there are 6 file servers, all ranging from about 3 to 6 TB of shared data individually.

There is no official best practices I am aware off. It actually depends on your needs. In any case, you can have multiple file server roles in a single Failover cluster. You should consider deploying DFS-N to structure your file shares and make future scale-out easier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/dfs-overview
The following guides should help with Failover Cluster configuration:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/deploy-two-node-clustered-file-server?tabs=server-manager
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-virtual-san-for-hyper-v-2-node-hyperconverged-scenario-with-windows-server-2016/
